# alert if the user didn't fill the required fields

Tags: asp.net

I have a field in asp and he has RequiredFieldValidator.
I have also a button that on click I send mail to the user.
my code:

```
<asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="mail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="ShemPrati"
                                        ErrorMessage="you must enter your mail"
                                        Display="Dynamic"
                                        ForeColor="Red"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     <asp:Button ID="Button4" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="send mail"  OnClick="Button4_Click" />
```

When I click on the button it's give me the ErrorMessage (if the field is empty).
I want also to alert a massage that he will be notify that there are a required fields in the form.
How can I do it?
thanks!

Comment: read javascript validations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by adding a client-side onclick event to the button that submits the form:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function checkIfFormIsValid() {
     //this will check if the form is valid
     if (Page_IsValid == false) {

        alert('Your form is not valid!');

     }

}

</script>
```

Then you can call the function when someone clicks your button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button4" OnClientClick="JAVASCRIPT:checkIfFormIsValid();" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="send mail"  OnClick="Button4_Click" />
```

BONUS:

You can add an onblur client-side event to a specific text box and do some custom stuff that way:

```
txtMail.Attributes.Add("onblur","javascript:checkIfFormIsValid();");
```